# unable to get rid off `seconds` clock from the date (angular pipe)

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using angular pipes to get time on the screen . My code is `today | date: 'medium'` which works perfectly and gets me output as : `Nov 5, 2019, 4:01:20 PM` . 
However, I need to get rid off the seconds clock and only want `Nov 5, 2019, 4:01 PM` on my screen. How can I remove the seconds clock with my existing approach

Comment: See this: https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#custom-format-options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `today | date: 'MMM d, y, h:mm a'` more options can be found [here](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)